# All operator alternative in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent of using `all` in SQL, within sqlite (which does not support the 'all' operator). For example, I would like to query instructors that teach all the same course as John Smith.

I'm trying to understand why my process is incorrect.

```
select distinct instructor
from testTable
where not exists(
    select course from testTable where not exists (
        select course from testTable where instructor = 'John Smith')
)
```

My thinking behind it was to find all courses that aren't the courses taught by John Smith, then the outer not exists will return all those instructors that teach the same course as John Smith.

Example Input and Outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (instructor TEXT, course TEXT);
INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Doe', 'Math');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Doe', 'English');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Doe', 'Physics');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('Jane Doe', 'Math');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Smith', 'Physics');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Smith', 'Math');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('Janice Smith', 'English');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('Janice Smith', 'Physics');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('James Smith', 'Math');
INSERT INTO testTable values ('James Smith', 'Physics');
```

Output should be:

```
James Smith
John Smith
John Doe
```

Comment: How would you do that with the `all`operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach used a self join followed by an aggregation by instructor to check that the number of matching courses agrees with John Smith's roster.

```
SELECT t1.instructor
FROM testTable t1
INNER JOIN testTable t2
    ON t1.course = t2.course AND
       t2.instructor = 'John Smith'
GROUP BY
    t1.instructor
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testTable WHERE instructor = 'John Smith');
```

This answer assumes that a given instructor/course pair appear only once and not in duplicate.  If not, then the above query would need to be slightly modified.